# gitlab.com CI - build a NodeJS app using docker in docker

Tags: node.js, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm currently facing a problem with the gitlab.com shared-runners. What I'm trying to archieve in my pipeline is:
 -  NPM install and using grunt to make some uncss, minimize and compress tasks
 -  Cleaning up
 -  Building a docker container with the app included
 -  Moving the container to gitlab registry

Unfortunateley I don't get it running since a long time! I tried a lot of different gitlab.ci configs - without success. The problem is, that I have to use the "image: docker:latest" to have all the docker-tools running. But then I don't have node and grunt installed in the container.
Also the other way around is not working. I was trying to use image: centos:latest and install docker manually - but this is also not working as I always just get a `Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted`
Does anyone has some more experience on the gitlab-ci using docker build commands in a docker shared runner?
Any help is highly appreciated!!

Thank you
Jannik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gitlab can be a bit tricky :) I dont have an example based on CentOS, but I have one based on Ubuntu if that helps you. Here is some copy paste of a working gitlab pipeline of mine which uses gulp (you should be easily able to adjust it to work with your grunt).

The .gitlab-ci.yml looks like this (adjust the CONTAINER... variables at the beginning):

```
variables:
  CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE: registry.gitlab.com/psono/psono-client:$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME
  CONTAINER_RELEASE_IMAGE: registry.gitlab.com/psono/psono-client:latest

stages:
  - build

docker-image:
  stage: build
  image: ubuntu:16.04
  services:
    - docker:dind
  variables:
    DOCKER_HOST: 'tcp://docker:2375'
  script:
    - sh ./var/build-ubuntu.sh
    - docker info
    - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p "$CI_BUILD_TOKEN" registry.gitlab.com
    - docker build -t $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE .
    - docker push $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE
```

in addition i have a this "./var/build-ubuntu.sh" which you can adjust a bit according to your needs, replace some ubuntu dependencies or switch gulp for grunt as needed:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
apt-get update && \
apt-get install -y libfontconfig zip nodejs npm git apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl openssl software-properties-common && \
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | apt-key add -  && \
add-apt-repository \
   "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
   $(lsb_release -cs) \
   stable" && \
apt-get update && \
apt-get install -y docker-ce && \
ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node && \
npm install && \
node --version && \
npm --version
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the fast answer. I was using ubuntu image and docker:dind under services - But still no success :( Every task concerning node is working but the moment I want to use docker-tools I get this answer: `/bin/bash: line 59: docker: command not found` What am I doing wrong? why is it working for you? :(

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: Give me a second, I can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Ok, I have upated my answer with something that works. Its a little bit "brute force" but does the trick.

Comment: seems like you are a real genius! I was trying and trying since weeks to get this running .. I never thought that my use-case is so "unusual" ..  Anyhow, thank you very much for the fast and correct answer!!

Comment: No problem. Gald I could help.